# jQuery How to find the next element with a specific attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have some `label` tags on my page, some of them has the `myAttr` attribute.

I select on of them like `$('label[myAttr="lorem"]')`

How to find the next `label` (with the `myAttr` attribute) after that one ? The value of the `myAttr` is different for each `label` tag.

Comment: Are they siblings? Can you post the relevant markup too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select all of the `<label>`s with that attribute like so:

```
$('label[myAttr]')
```

and traverse that collection using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). If you've already got that collection, and just want to hop from `$('label[myAttr="lorem"]')` to the next `<label>` with that attribute, this will work:

```
var $labels = $('label[myAttr]');
var $current = $('label[myAttr="lorem"]');
var currentIndex = $labels.index($current);
var $next = $labels.eq(currentIndex + 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xZKGk

**N.B.** I don't recommend doing that in a loop because of its asymptotic runtime behavior.

Comment: You can't use `next()` like that, for it will select the element following the first element, not the next element in the original set of elements. http://jsfiddle.net/s75fP/

Comment: I'd say it works. Updated your fiddle for a bit capsulation and handling last in row cases: http://jsfiddle.net/xZKGk/1/

Comment: Oh nice, that's funky! :) Thanks for pointing that out, much more elegant.

Comment: On second thought... why is 3%5 3? Does the modulo operator always return a if a<b, for a%b?

Comment: @kontur yes, [that's how modulus works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.C2.A0.25_%28Modulus%29). _"The modulo function is the integer remainder of dividing `var1` by `var2`...  The result will have the same sign as `var1`; that is, `−1 % 2` returns `−1`."_